# AWS Lambda, what type of request does the test button do?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, post, aws-lambda

AWS Lambda newbie here.
I was doing some testing with AWS Lambda functions and there is something that it is not working correct for me.
Given this lambda function:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    var response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        response: event.talk
    };
    callback(null, response);
};
```

When I press the [test button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aLhN.jpg) with this content ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF3V6.jpg) is a screenshot):

```
{
   "talk": "Hello World"
}
```

I get this response ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpRqi.jpg) is a screenshot):

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
},
  "response": "Hello World"
}
```

But when I make a POST request (I added an open API gateway, see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmz5m.jpg)), it just returns empty data and sometimes internal server error ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DW1ou.jpg) is a screenshot):

```
no data
```

If I modify my Lambda function to JSON parse the body, it will work

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    var body = JSON.parse(event.body);
    var talk = body.talk;
    var response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(talk)
    };
    callback(null, response);
};
```

What it is happening? Why the test button work differently from a POST request? I want both to work, specially the test because I want to "debug" the "serverless"

Comment: can you add a screen shot of the integration part of the API GW, That might help shed some light on this.

Comment: Got it, added in the description https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmz5m.jpg

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When You call **AWS lambda** handle request what you pass in the request.

> So, When you need to pass data in `event` with body just add `body` params in `event` Object.

```
{
 "body": "{\"talk\":\"Hello World\"}"
}
```

**Note:**

> When you Call lambda from `POST` then request Object contain `body` in the event.

Comment: Oh Thanksl for the explanation :D
Both test button and POST request work now

Comment: Quick question... What Javascript method did you use to convert from the object {talk: "Hello World"} to "{\"talk\":\"Hello World\"}" ?

Answer (score 2):

The test button will simply run your lambda with the event provided, but when you run it through API gateway proxy, you get an event in a different format. As to why it works when you parse event.body, it's because event.body will contain the message being sent through the API.

The best thing to do would be to do:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
```

And view the incoming event format.

Comment: Where can I see the console.log() results every time I make a post request?

Comment: All logs for the lambda are recorded in CloudWatch by default. You can go there through the CloudWatch service, or directly through the lambda console by going to the "Monitoring" tab and then clicking on "View logs in CloudWatch".

Comment: The logs are not really helpful, they just show the request started and finished...
Is there a way to see the stack trace?

Comment: The logs will have anything you put into console.log(), or if an error occurred during execution that will show up as well. Are you calling that in the function?